# The sequence $f_n = \frac{1}{n} \mathcal{X}_{[0,n]}$ is not weakly convergent in $L_1(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-convergence

Let $f_n(x) = \frac{1}{n} \mathcal{X}_{[0,n]}(x)$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ be a sequence in $L_1(\mathbb{R})$.

How can we show that $f_n$ is not weakly convergent in $L_1(\mathbb{R})$?

I tried to use the evaluation map but I could not prove it is bounded as I am working on unbounded set.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $(f_n)$ converges weakly to some function $f$. Using the definition of weakly convergent sequence, the following convergence should take place for each $a<b$, $a,b\in\mathbb R$:
$$
\int f_n\mathbf{1}_{(a,b)}d\lambda\to \int f\mathbf{1}_{(a,b)}d\lambda.
$$
But the first term converges to $0$ for each fixed $a<b$, as for $n$ large enough $\left\lvert \int f_n\mathbf{1}_{(a,b)}d\lambda\right\rvert\leqslant (b-a)/n$. Therefore, $\int f\mathbf{1}_{I}d\lambda=0$ for each interval $I$ and this implies that $f=0$. However, we reach a contradiction observing that the limit cannot be $0$: test the weak convergence with the constant function equal to $1$.

Comment: Do you mean constant function equal to $1$?

Comment: @podiki Yes! Thanks.